# Smooth scrolling for WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scroll

I am using WPF datagrid, only modification I have in place is:

```
    <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
       <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
       <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
      </Style>
    </toolkit:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

I have this modification so if the cell contents are longer, they stretch the line height, no text is hidden.
Problem is with DataGrid's scrolling behaviour - it jumps whole lines when scrolling, which does not work well at all if the row is higher than one line - scrollbar is jerking on scrolling etc.

Is there any way to make WPF DataGrid scroll "smoothly" and not line by line?

Thanks

Answer (score 34):

I haven't played with the DataGrid explicitly, but it is factual that using `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll=False` swaps out the default `ItemsPanelTemplate` which uses the `VirtualizedStackPanel` with a regular `StackPanel`.  It will scroll smoothly, but it will be rendering every item even if it's not visible.

This can absolutely kill performance if you're dealing with either a complex visual tree or large datasets.

Comment: This answer is more precise, since it warns about the danger of disabling ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll and VirtualizedStackPanel.

Answer (score 30):

The `DataGrid` has an Attached property, `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll`, that manages this behavior. To get smooth scrolling you'll need to set it to `False`.

Comment: That property is in the ScrollViewer namespace: `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"`

Comment: Tried this for 2500 rows x 20 columns DataTable bounded DataGrid and received unresponsive program, over 1GB memory consumption and after few seconds I stopped waiting for loading to finish.

Comment: @JānisGruzis That is a different problem. This is talking about the datagrid scrolling one row at a time rather than smoothly. For the problem you're talking about it sounds like you have the entire grid showing in a ScrollViewer or Panel and you're scrolling that so the DataGrid things the whole thing is showing. You need to use the Grid's internal scroll viewer.

Comment: Awesome!  And for those who need it programmatically...  dataGrid1.SetValue(ScrollViewer.CanContentScrollProperty, false);

Comment: I suggest using `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"`, this don't disable Virtualization.

Answer (score 26):

Use this:

```
<DataGrid VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel">
```

Dont use `CanContentScroll="False"`. It disables virtualisation, which can causes long loading times when you have a lot of rows. Virtualisation means it will only render the data that is shown and not all the data of the datagrid.

However, disabling virtualization can be helpful if you don't have too many rows, but each row is complex to create (complex datatemplates/controls, a lot of data etc. in each row).

Comment: @Ralms it is an attached property. I never tried that, but a quick google search revealed that attached properties can be set this way. when your Datagrid is named like this `<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid"...>` you would set the attached property like this `VirtualizingPanel.SetScrollUnit(MyDataGrid, ScrollUnit.Pixel);`

Comment: Yes that is using the XAML. On my case a lot of the UI is being generated with code on the .cs file, I just created generator functions to add the same element over and over again. 
So in this case I'm doing the normal "var myDG = new DataGrid()" and I don't know how to access those attached properties. Any idea?

Comment: @Ralms Should be the same process. just use myDG as name VirtualizingPanel.SetScrollUnit(myDG , ScrollUnit.Pixel);

Comment: thank you so much, worked like a charm. Didn't know about that way for "Attached properties".

Comment: VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" did nothing for me regarding smooth scrolling.

Answer (score -3):

```
  <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
              CanUserAddRows="False" 
              CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
              CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
              CanUserSortColumns="False" 
              SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
              HeadersVisibility="None"
              Name="grd" 
              GridLinesVisibility="None"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
</DataGrid>
```