# WPF DataGrid filtered items, jumpy scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with an `ItemSource` populating the control. I also use a filter/query mechanism which filters the content of the control.

When the datagrid is not filtered, scrolling works fine. But when I filtered (=set visibility to items to false, which collapses the item in the datagrid) the scrolling becomes very 'jumpy'. When I scroll down, the scrollbar becomes larger and smaller, and scrolling becomes an annoying experience.

I read something about [virtualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383613/how-can-i-get-a-datagrid-to-scroll-smoothly-when-the-row-is-taller-than-the-view), and something about settings the [DataGrid.ScrollViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303120/smooth-scrolling-for-wpf-datagrid), but I have neither of those properties available in XAML.

Why is something which feels trivial so overly complicated... Anyway, how can I configure my datagrid to:

- show the list of items via data binding
- being able to filter the list (by collapsing items)
- and obviously having a scrollbar which allows users to scroll without getting frustrated :)

My XAML:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ErrorsThatStoppedMachine}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedError}"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          SelectionMode="Single">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Timestamp" Width="220" Binding="{Binding Path=Timestamp}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ErrorCode" Width="90" Binding="{Binding Path=ErrorCode}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit" Width="70" Binding="{Binding Path=Unit}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="State" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=MachineState}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Message}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"
               d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance IsDesignTimeCreatable=True, Type=viewModels:ErrorViewModel}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Many many thanks in advance.

PS: some additional explanation would be greatly appreciated, would be a nice bonus to actually learn something from this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataGrid has a `ViewPort` and will only render and calculate things that are actually shown. This is know as virtualization. Visual changes depending on Row/Cell Data will inevitably cause 'jumping', since the DataGrid will calculate them on the spot.

Settings on the `Scrollviewer`, as well as putting the Grid inside a `Scrollviewer`, will disable virtualization. This means the whole grid will be rendered at once:

- The Grid can scroll smoothly
- The initial load time for the Grid will be higher: to an extend it will become unusable, when too much data is attached to the grid.

If your Grid will only contain a limited amount of rows, this might be ok.

---

A much better approach to this problem would be to filter directly on the `ItemsSource`. Use a [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) and filter your data there. The Grid will display the rows accordently to the `ObservableCollection`.

This is exaclty the behavior you rebuilt with this RowStyle that sets Visibility.

Comment: That really helped! Will definitely look into filtering the ObservableCollection directly. For now wrapping the DataGrid in a ScrollViewer solves the problem. Been pulling my hair out for long enough, so I am really happy with your answer!! :)