Deactivate horizontal focus scrolling in DataGrids
My C# WPF project with DataGrids has this annoying DataGrid horizontal scrolling behavior, that clicking a cell that reaches out of sight leads to horizontal scrolling to show the whole cell. I don't want that. Horizontal scrolling should only happen through the horizontal scrolling scrollbar.
This shows how the left DataGrid was scrolled because I clicked a part of a cell
I have no clue how to prevent this behavior.
Here is a way to reproduce this:
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                
                    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                    CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                    CanUserResizeRows="False"
                    CanUserSortColumns="True"
                                  
                    x:Name="MyDataGrid_BusLog" IsReadOnly="True" 
                    SelectionMode="Extended" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    >
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

and
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = "Line";
            column.Binding = new Binding("Line");
            MyDataGrid_BusLog.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = "TelTyp";
            column.Binding = new Binding("TelTyp");
            MyDataGrid_BusLog.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = "State";
            column.Binding = new Binding("State");
            MyDataGrid_BusLog.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = "Timestamp_ms";
            column.Binding = new Binding("Timestamp_ms");
            MyDataGrid_BusLog.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = "EC";
            column.Binding = new Binding("EC");
            MyDataGrid_BusLog.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = "Date";
            column.Binding = new Binding("Date");
            MyDataGrid_BusLog.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = "Time";
            column.Binding = new Binding("Time");
            MyDataGrid_BusLog.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = "QQ";
            column.Binding = new Binding("QQ");
            MyDataGrid_BusLog.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = "ZZ";
            column.Binding = new Binding("ZZ");
            MyDataGrid_BusLog.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = "PBSB";
            column.Binding = new Binding("PBSB");
            MyDataGrid_BusLog.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = "NN";
            column.Binding = new Binding("NN");
            MyDataGrid_BusLog.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = "Data";
            column.Binding = new Binding("Data");
            MyDataGrid_BusLog.Columns.Add(column);


            MyDataGrid_BusLog.Items.Add(new DataItem 
{ Line = "1", TelTyp = "MS", State = "OK", Timestamp_ms = "1111", EC = "0",
                Date = "2024-10-09",Time = "17:05:30.1234",QQ = "30",ZZ = "70",PBSB = "0704",NN = "0",Data = "50 10 20 70 90 34 65 A3 BD 3D 32 00" });

            MyDataGrid_BusLog.Items.Add(new DataItem
            {Line = "1",TelTyp = "SYN",State = "OK",Timestamp_ms = "1200",EC = "0",
            Date = "2024-10-09",Time = "17:05:30.2000",QQ = "AA",ZZ = "AA",PBSB = "AAAA",NN = "AA",
            Data = "AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA"
            });
            
    }
    
}


sorry, in the code to reproduce this, I forgot to add following code:
public class DataItem
{
public string Line { get; set; }
public string TelTyp { get; set; }
public string State { get; set; }
public string Timestamp_ms { get; set; }
public string Date { get; set; }
public string Time { get; set; }
public string QQ { get; set; }
public string ZZ { get; set; }
public string PBSB { get; set; }
public string NN { get; set; }
public string Data { get; set; }
}

see if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303120/smooth-scrolling-for-wpf-datagrid

Nope, ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll=False ruins performance and also doesn't even solve the issue, horizontal focus scrolling is still not deactivated

also the  VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" didn't help ?

Nope, horizontal focus scrolling is still not deactivated

the other option that I can think of is ugly , register to the scroll event and mark it as handled when the source of the scroll is the focus \ click
